# Unable to capture text in popup list

Tags: windows, python-3.x, user-interface, pyautogui

I am using python3.6 with pyautogui to create a script that can automate button clicks on an application. The application is capable of loading many (hundreds) different input scripts which are contained in a file. On the application GUI to select an input script you just need to click a button which pops up a selection window. In the selection window the names of all the scripts are listed so you scroll (if needed), click one to highlight it, and then click OK to close the popup.

When my script runs it already knows which script it needs to select and has the name. I was thinking I could easily click on the first script in the popup and check the name by copying it to the clipboard and writing it down in a file to compare the values (if there is a match stop, if not press the  down key with pyautogui and continue comparing, yes I realize this is slow).

The problem is that there is no way to get the name of the scripts in the popup window. For some reason (maybe due to the properties of the GUI) I cannot <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> the text on the list entries in the popup, when I do the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> gives nothing. Nothing happens when I right click a list entry either. I do not know if I am wasting my time trying to find a way to do this. Is there a way by which to get the text of whatever is selected by the mouse? I haven't been able to find anything on stack overflow yet. If there is no way to get the name of the list entry does anyone know of another approach? I have heard openCV can be used to detect text on screen but seems complicated.

Note: not a full time programmer and first time asking a question on stack overflow, so sorry if this is poorly worded.

Comment: Show us the code! You should review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: For this part I don't have any code yet because ctrl+c ctrl+v does not work manually so I assume it will not when I use pyautogui. Here I am looking for a python tool/approach so I can capture the needed text.